# Как отключить в Apex 5.0.3 HttpOnly session cookies?

Tags: java, oracle, cookie, applet, j2ee

Собственно проблема заключается в том, что я из java applet отправляю запрос на скачку файла, а в Apex 5.0 добавили поддержку HttpOnly cookies. И к сожалению никаких настроек по отключению не предусмотрено. (java applet не имеет доступа к таким кукам и потому при отправке запроса - теряется сессия)
Если не путём отключения в Apex, то может есть расширение какое? Или всё же есть способ цеплять такой кук?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему получилось решить только одним способом. К сожалению, не самым лучшим - в APEX'овской схеме БД ***APEX_050000*** есть package ***"wwv_flow_response"*** в котором находится процедура "cookie". На вход она помимо остальных параметров получает HttpOnly.

Тело package оказалось зашифровано, для преобразование в исходный вид применяются любые утилиты unwrap.

В преобразованном package в теле процедуры ***"cookie"***  переменной (НЕ ПАРАМЕТРУ) ***L_HTTPONLY*** насильно прописываем false. 
Готово - cookie отправляются в не защищённом с помощью HttpOnly виде.

Интересно есть ли более элегантное решение? Ведь даже получив права на локальной машине, апплет всё равно не цепляет уже имеющиеся в браузере cookie.

Если бы получилось, можно было бы подписать applet.